# Incorrect data after modifying post using backlink from wp_die

Tags: custom-field, hooks

I have hook:

```
function myHook( $post_ID, $post )
{
    $data = get_post_meta($post_ID, 'data', true);
    if ($data)
    {
        _log('data:' . $data);
        /* here some checks and validation */
        if (!valid)
            wp_die('Error', 'Error',  array( 'response' => 500, 'back_link' => true ));
    }
    else 
        wp_die('Error', 'Error',  array( 'response' => 500, 'back_link' => true ));
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'myHook', 0, 2 );
```

Problem is that when data is incorrect and user uses back_link to correct data and tries to publish post again, his changes are not applied. Old data is taken into analysis. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by ***Old Data*** and ***Correct Data*** ? :::: I applied your code and don't see any anomaly when hitting the `Back Link`; nice trick, btw!

Comment: I mean when in data i have 'a', validation fails, user clicks back_link, changes 'a' to 'b' and presses 'publish', data in myHook is still 'a'.

Comment: additional issue is that title (and only title) is cleared after pressing back link, but let's say it's less important

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this issue occurs. The `back_link` is created in [`/wp-includes/functions.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-includes/functions.php#L2062). If [there were](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22history.back%22) a Javascript solution, it could be applied in the message of `wp_die`. For example:

```
$msg = 'Error' . "\n<p><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>$back_text</a></p>";
wp_die($msg, 'Error',  array( 'response' => 500 ));
```

But this didn't work...

What I saw is that the *Title* and the default *Custom Fields* meta box are the only ones that don't preserve the value when the browser goes back in history.
The *Content*, *Custom Meta Boxes with Custom Fields*, the *Category* and others preserve the value.

A workaround is putting your Custom Fields values inside a [Custom Meta Box](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/plugins/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-writemeta-boxes/).

Observation: when hooking in the `save_post` action, there are some checks that you need/may do:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'myHook', 0, 2 );
function myHook( $post_ID, $post )
{
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE
            or ! isset ( $_POST['post_type'] )
            or 'post' !== $_POST['post_type']
            or wp_is_post_revision( $post_ID )
        )
        return; // <-- NOT the correct action, stop hook

    $post_meta = get_post_meta($post_ID, 'data', true);
    if ($post_meta)
    {
        // _validation_function();
    }
    else 
        wp_die('Error, please enter Data Field.', 'Error',  array( 'response' => 500, 'back_link' => true ));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer and tip with checks. I'll try them.