# displaying an error before update_post_meta

Tags: wp-admin, post-meta, save-post

I'm trying to restrict how many items you can associate with a post so in my save function I have:

```
add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_custom_items_data' ), 10, 2 );

public function save_custom_items_data( $post_id, $post ) {
    if(count($related_items) > 5) {
        // display error message here but the page redirects anyway...
    } else {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_custom-meta-items', $related_items );
    }
}
```

how do I display an error here instead of saving the custom post meta?

Comment: There's not enough code here to be useful.

Comment: added some more code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of doing some jQuery validation, I think the only option is [`wp_die()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_die).

```
add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_custom_items_data' ), 10, 2 );

public function save_custom_items_data( $post_id, $post ) 
{
    if( count( $related_items ) > 5 ) 
    {
        wp_die(
            'Error, 5 items max.', 
            'Error',  
            array( 
                'response' => 500, 
                'back_link' => true 
            )
        );    
    } 
    else 
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_custom-meta-items', $related_items );
}
```

Related Q&A's:

- [Incorrect data after modifying post using backlink from wp_die](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/80375/12615)
- [Require tags for bbPress topics](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/82956/12615)